# reading values from dynamically created Webcontrol

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I have a Webcontrol, that I create completely dynamically and it contains radiobuttonList. How can I acces this radibuttonlist values, on pages where I register this control?

public class MyControl: WebControl

```
  pnContainer = new Panel();
  rbl = new RadioButtonList();
  liResume = new ListItem("Resume", "Resume");
  liReopen = new ListItem("ReOpen", "ReOpen");
  rbl.Items.Add(liResume); 
  rbl.Items.Add(liReopen); 

  pnContainer.Controls.Add(lblReOpenTitle);
  pnContainer.Controls.Add(rbl);
  this.Controls.Add(pnContainer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always exist 2 ways:

1. Just ensure that after postback you
   have recreated your radibuttonlist.
   Then using FindControl locate this
   list and get back your data
2. You can directly access data passed from client with help of
   Request.Form, but in this case you
   need to know real name of
   radibuttonlist (see Control.UniqueID
   property)